# How do you resolve static pages in multiple controllers with different @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, annotations, request-mapping

I have 2 different controllers annotated with `@RequestMapper`, one specifying `"/"` and the other specifying `"/rmo"`. 
The controller with `"/"` properly resolves static resources such as `.css` and `.js` files. The resources used by the controller with `"/rmo"` in the `@RequestMapping` have `/rmo` prefixed to the URLs for the static resources. 
 How do I get the `/rmo` controller to properly resolve the static resources?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. In my ApplicationConfiguration which extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter I have the following override:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
{
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
        logger.debug("addResourceHandlers");

    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
```

By adding the following line, my problem is apparently solved:

```
    registry.addResourceHandler("/rmo/**").addResourceLocations(RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
```

I guess I'll have to do this for each controller.